# PHP MYSQL API, error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user..." petición remota

Tags: php, mysql, api

estoy desarrollando una API Restfull desde 0 con PHP (sin frameworks) y aunque el código me funciona perfectamente en local, cuando lo subo al servidor recibo el error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user...".

La parte del código que me da error es al instanciar la conexión, así:

`$this->conn= new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name,$this->username,$this->password);`

Las peticiones las hago a través de POSTMAN (GET); de este modo:

http://miservidor.com/api/get_data.php?id=3

Tengo en conocimiento que mi servidor de hosting tiene capadas las conexiones al servidor MySQL desde fuera, pero por ello estoy programando una API.

Estoy haciendo algo mal? Algún fallo de concepto?

Muchas gracias. 
Un saludo.

---

El usuario y contraseña son correctos.

Respecto a cambiar el colantion, no se, me da un poco de cosa, es una BBDD que utilizan decenas de usuarios y no me quiero arriesgar a simplemente hacer ese cambio. Además que no veo relación ya que ni el usuario ni la contraseña tiene carácteres fuera de Letras en minúsucula y mayúsculas, y números.

Gracias por tu respuesta oskar hernandez.

Un saludo.

Comment: El collation de la base de datos está a utf8_general_ci Parece que ese no es el error tampoco.

Comment: Usa el enlace "editar" para agregar actualizaciones a tu pregunta @juanjo

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que las credenciales no sean validas, trata de verificarlas, si ese no es el problema intenta entonces (si estas usando PHPmyAdmin) de modificar el cotejamiento de la BD a: "utf8_general_ci". Cuando tuve ese problema a mi me sirvió. Aqui consegui solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031874/unexpected-exception-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-localh